# Daterange till with null date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this example

```
FROM           TILL
2016-02-27  2016-12-31
2017-01-01    <null>
```

I need the dates between 2013 and 2017, but when the TILL-Date is null this query doesn´t work. I just get the first row, not the second. Tryed it with from > COALESCE('2017',null) but this doenst work.

```
where not (FROM > '2017-12-31' or TILL < '2013-01-01' )
```

edit Tim

```
FROM           TILL
2017-06-16  2018-05-31
2018-06-01  <null>
```

Comment: `COALESCE(field, value-if-null)`. You didn’t use it properly

Comment: Same, just the range 2016-02 to 2016-12. Tryed COALESCE(FROM,NULL) >= '2018-12-31'

Comment: @Abra: `coalesce()` **is** part of standard ANSI SQL

Comment: @HellaF10: the second parameter to `coalesce()` should be a non-null value, e.g. `coalesce("FROM", date '2100-01-01')`

Comment: From is just a example for the name. Its Postgres

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following logic:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    "FROM" <= '2013-01-01' AND
    (TILL > '2018-12-31' OR TILL IS NULL);
```

This would include all records whose `FROM` to `TILL` range spans the years 2013-2018, inclusive.  I am assuming that you are storing dates only, not timestamps.  Otherwise, you would need to compare `TILL` against `2018-12-31 23:59:59`.

Please avoid naming your columns and other database objects using reserved keywords such as `FROM`.  Otherwise, you will have to escape those name in all your code.

Comment: The problem is, that now FROM: 2017-01-11  TO: 2018-03-12 doenst get recognized. Above is just a small example. That´s the third case, forgot it in the example above.

Comment: Sorry, till 2017 and not to 2018. I add a example for you in my question. WIth your sql i just get the ``2018-06-01  <null>`` and not the row before

Comment: Sorry, I botched the logic.  You want the `FROM` to `TILL` range to cover whatever date range you have in mind.

Comment: Yes... from 2013 till 2017 that includes everything. Just have to hit. And your new logic doenst work. The logic before was better, this exludes like everything.

Answer (score 1):

When using Postgres you have a better way of dealing with that - you can create a date range that can easily deal with a NULL value in the upper bound:

```
select *
from the_table
where daterange(from_date, till_date, '[]') && daterange(date '2013-01-01', date '2018-01-01', '[)')
```

The `&&` is the "overlaps" operator - you can't really use the "contains" operator (`@>`) because your row with the `null` value for `till` means "from 2017-01-01 to eternity" and a closed range like from 2013 to 2017 does not "include" a range that runs until "eternity"

Online example: https://rextester.com/KBMK53890

Answer (score 0):

try like below add null checking for till in where condition

```
where (FROM>='2013-01-01' and till<='2018-12-31')
or (FROM>='2013-01-01' and till is null)
```

another way by using `coalesce()`

```
 where FROM>='2013-01-01' and coalesce(till,'2018-12-31')<='2018-12-31')
```